# BlueMix service error with Android app - 'Unknown pattern character 'X''

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I'm developing an android application and am attempting to integrate the Bluemix service - Personality Insights. However, due to a conflict with dates (Bluemix service is assuming a Java SimpleDateFormat which includes the symbol 'X', while Android's SimpleDateFormat does not include this symbol) causing an error (Log below). My question is this, is there a way to brute force the app to use the Java SimpleDateFormat version as opposed the Android version? other than that I don't see how I can use the service without Bluemix switching to accomodate the 'X' character in dates. Any enlightening on this topic would be appreciated!

Log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'
            at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePatternCharacter(SimpleDateFormat.java:314)
            at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:303)
            at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:356)
            at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.<init>(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:49)
            at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.addTypeAdaptersForDate(GsonBuilder.java:555)
            at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.create(GsonBuilder.java:543)
            at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton.createGson(GsonSingleton.java:53)
            at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton.getGson(GsonSingleton.java:38)
            at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.concept_expansion.v1.ConceptExpansion.createJob(ConceptExpansion.java:147)
            at intercept.notification.notify.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$Persona.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:106)
            at intercept.notification.notify.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$Persona.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:84)
```

I've debugged this quite a bit but don't know how to brute force use of the Java version of SimpleDataFormat as opposed the Android version. Differences between the two can be seen here: 
Java (which includes symbol 'X' as required by Bluemix service - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Android (which doesn't include it) - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Seems like you are confusing Bluemix with Watson. Bluemix is the platform that will host your Android app. Watson is the service you are trying to use (Personality Insights). Take a look at the Watson Developer Cloud: https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

We were using 'X' which is not supported by the jdk 1.6 in Android.
That problem was fixed in v1.1.1.

### Updating the Dependency

1. Maven:

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>java-wrapper</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>`
2. Gradle:

`'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-wrapper:1.1.1'`

3. Downloading the [jar-with-dependencies](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases/download/java-wrapper-1.1.1/java-wrapper-1.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar) from github.

Comment: Ah perfect, that did the trick.. I was using v1.1.0! now working! Thanks!